# Text in a spinner changes height and width selecting another item of the spinner

Tags: android, eclipse, text, spinner

I wrote this code for an Android spinner:

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/lstCommunity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/community_string"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="@drawable/box" />
```

But the text in the spinner changes is height and width after selecting another item in the list.

So, initially it is a bit smaller than the height and width of the spinner, after selecting another item, it becomes really bigger than the spinners size.

How should i change my code?

FIRST EDIT:
I am trying to use the spinner in order to choose some text from a list.

(I can't post an image)

The text initially fits the spinner but after selecting another option in the dropdown menu the text becomes greater than the spinner box.

EDIT 2:
Java code related to the spinner:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lstCommunity);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: could you clarify what you are trying to do, and possibly add some of the code.

Comment: It looks like your layout might be a little more complicated than it needs to be. "align bottom" means "align my bottom to this bottom". I suggest removing that one. I also suggest removing minHeight 0dp (what's the point of that? height will never be negative). It'd also be helpful if you posted the entire layout, and not just this one spinner.

Comment: @argablarga The min height is due do the fact that usually widgets in Android have a minimum Height that didn't fit to my layout so i added "Minimum Height" line

Comment: post your activity code relevant to spinner please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Creare spinnertext.xml in res/layout

For example:

```
  xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/.    apk/res/android"
  android:text="@+id/TextView01"
  android:id="@+id/TextView01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="12sp"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
  android:gravity="center"/>
```

2)Declare the spinner in the file main.xml (in res\layout), to manage its size :

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dip"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt"
     />
```

3) Declare the spinner in the activity

```
 Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  ArrayAdapter adapter =   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sensors, R.layout.spinnertext);      
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
 //when an item is selected call the selectSensor method
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,     int position, long id) {
        selectSensor(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
  }
  @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        }
     });
```

Notice the change in the createfromresource function.

Source: http://android2ee.blogspot.it/2011/11/spinner-managing-size-and-text.html

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem. There seems to be easy solution for this, Try getting the longest option available in spinner. Note it's size and hardcode the value like

```
  <spinner
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
```

Note: 120dp and 40dp are just for examples and need to be adjusted according to your example